# Image names from assets catalog is not showing up in auto completion - xcode 12

Tags: swift, assets, xcode12

I am trying to set **UIColor** from image pattern. But I am unable to access the image set by name in ***xcode 12***.
I saved the image set by **"BMW"** name. I want If I write **BMW** it should pre-populate in suggestion and small image of BMW should shown up.
I tried to set like this -

`node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Earth Day")`

But it is showing up as
[node image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOwE0.png)

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of your assets catalog as well? You can blur the images if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I got it now.

Although images names are still not pre populating, but we can pick the images from assets by typing **#imageLiteral()** and double click on it, one popup will open that lets you pick any image from assets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIImage(named:"BMW")` to access the image from your assets folder

Comment: Yes, But I want to know how it will work that way. I want to show image icon in xcode editor like we use to do in earlier xcode verisons.

Comment: That feature is gone. It didn’t work out.